# Civimail wont send (but Civi email will)

Tags: wordpress, civimail, checksum, mosaico

bit weird but here's whats happening

I use the Mosaico extension (thank you very much) to do bulk emails.  Ive been using it for some months with no issues.  About a month ago I included a few Civi tokens including a checksum for contacts to update their details - all good.. or so I thought

I started to get complaints that long time recipients weren't getting the weekly newsletter.  The non receipt started when I included the checksum.

After a few wrong turns the issue turned out to be that every time someone used the checksum to update their details Civimail wont recognise their record

There is nothing wrong with their email address - I know this because I can click on the contact, send an email and they receive it.

The only way to rectify this that I've found is to go through every field on their personal details and recreate it, save it and then Civimail will see the record. Presumably the details they have updated are causing the problem but I can't tell what they changed so have to do them all

any suggestions to what might be going on ( and how to fix it!)

thanks

Civi 4.7.14 Wordpress 4.7.5

Answer (score 1):

well the answer turned out to be using a profile that included the "is deceased" field.  Somehow that was setting that field to Null and Civimail didnt like that.

Setting the "is deceased" field to 0 fixed it up and all good now